# How to store Soda Water or other Home Made Sodas?

Tags: storage-method, storage, soda, carbonation

I have a SodaStream which I use to make soda water.  My wife recently started purchasing very tasty, but relatively expensive soda drinks from the store, including "Rose Lemonade" (here: [http://www.amazon.com/Fentimans-Rose-Lemonade-Soda-Bottle/dp/B00513EV60](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00513EV60)), and a pumkin ginger root beer.  I offered to try to make equivalents at home, which worked out really well, by combining Torani Syrup, fresh ingredients (like Ginger Juice from Centrifugal juicer, or Lemon Juice from a lemon), and soda water from the Soda Stream.

OK, so everything is great, except now when I make a batch, my Soda Stream bottle is "in use" until we finish that batch.  So I bought a few of these on Amazon, with rubber gasket seals: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0000CFMBL/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CFMBL).

But here's the problem:

***when I transfer the soda water from the Soda Stream bottle to the glass bottle, it fizzes up and loses most of it's carbonation.  Is there any way to avoid this, or a technique I can use to pour it with less "fizz loss"?***

Please let me know if more information would be helpful, and thanks so much!!!

Comment: Buy more sodastream bottles?

Comment: How do you pour? Do you use a funnel? How quickly do you pour? and what are pouring first? Do you add SodaStream water to the mix, or do you add the mix to the SodaStreamed water?

Comment: @TFD thanks, that probably would have been a good solution to begin with :/

Comment: @Layna I have tried pouring a few ways: 1) tilted glass bottle and slow pour, like a beer for very little head.  2) with a funnel, which was the worst - as the foam forms really fast.  I tried poring the soda water in first, and then adding the mix ingredients, but that made more foam too, so now I add the mix ingredients first, and add the soda water after.  Feedback much appreciated!

Comment: @ShamirColloff my suggestion would have been the tilted approach, too... only remaining thing I can come up with: wash the glass-bottles out first, so they are wet when you try transferring. Except for that... if not SodaStream bottles, anythign with a wide openenig.

Comment: @layna thanks!  I will try wet bottles, great idea!

Comment: Also make sure the bottle is pre-chilled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More sodastream bottles is the best option if you are starting from a sodastream.

The best other alternative is to act just like a really old-fashioned soda counter.

- Mix and store your syrups/flavors.
- Measure syrup into the glass.
- Add plain soda-water and mix.

Thus, your sodastream bottle only ever has plain carbonated water in it, not a specific flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Carbonated liquids lose their carbonation very quickly when at room temperature, when agitated, and when pushed through small orifices at room pressure.

You can't change the "small orifices" part due to your bottle design (and, honestly, these aren't that small so it isn't as bad as, say, a needle valve).  But you can change the temperature.  Cool the liquid until almost icy before charging it, then pour slowly (reduced agitation) into a pre-chilled glass bottle.  If you can, tilt the bottle so it runs down the side of the bottle inside, rather than as a stream into the liquid on the bottom.

The biggest difference will be made by making sure everything is ice cold, though.